# Map Reduce job in java for distcp

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distcp

I am trying to copy data from one cluster to another on daily basis. Searched a lot but everybody is suggesting to to call main function of DistCp with args. I was wring java code for same. But its not working also i didn't got any error. distcp on command line is working fine. What needs to be done here?

```
public static void customDiscp(String source, String destination) throws Exception {
  String[] args = new String[4];
  args[0] = "-log";
  args[1] = "/projects/logs";
  args[2] = source;
  args[3] = destination;
  DistCp.main(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For writing a map reduce job in Java you will have to use map reduce api.
Refer this tutorial to write a mr job

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html